Is there a software that updates cross-references automatically?
Some of my footnotes refer to other parts of my text, for example "See page 9" or "See footnote 59." When I edit my text or add another footnote, sometimes the part that these footnotes refer to are shifted to another page or the footnote numbers change, and I need to update the page and footnote numbers in these cross-references.
Is there a software that updates these cross-references automatically?

Vincent, I edited your question. I think you didn't find what you were looking for because you used the wrong term. If you search the internet for "cross-reference MS Word", for example, you find many explanations on how to do this.

@Ben I was waiting to answer because I dont have access to a desktop at the moment. I primarily use an iPad for Word and it doesnt have the ability to do cross-references. I‘ll try using a school computer to see if it works.

Your word processor can't do it? Frankly, that's hard to believe. MS Word could do it by 2003 at the latest, OpenOffice (ancestor of LibreOffice) could do it by 2008 at the latest, by now I'd for sure expect it from any similar software out there.

@Divizna Apparently Word for iPad doesn't have the functionality to do cross-references.

This question is about Google Docs which has add-ons available. If asking about software you need to specify what hardware/OS you're using and any other restriction (e.g. whether you want it online or standalone, free or paid, if you've a system with limited memory, etc).

But of course! Both MS Word and LibreOffice have such a feature (not saying they're the only ones to, either; they're just the ones I know this about - I'd expect the same of any word processor). They won't update the cross-references automatically as you edit the document (at least not the old versions that I have access to), but if you select all, you can update them all at once with one click or keyboard shortcut. Look for Insert > Cross-reference, and I think you can figure it out from there.

Hi, I looked at the cross-reference options for Word and its exactly what I needed, thanks!

@VincentDesrosiers I was surprised to hear that the iPad version leaves it out. Glad you can get your hands on an alternative.
